# Datatrics in magento: how to make scripts dynamic?

Tags: javascript, magento, dynamic-values

We are trying to implement these **DATATRICS** scripts within Magento 1.9.4.

The scripts are provided as static: my problem is that I cannot identify the exact magento variables to be specified in the scripts to make them "dynamic"

Could you help me by indicating the exact "**dynamic**" values?

Is there a list of values on the web? Where can i get them?

The values ​​should be replaced instead of "NAME", "SKU" ..etc and instead of the numeric (static) values ​​declared in the example scripts.

Thanks to those who will be able to help me

```
// add the first product to the order
_paq.push(['addEcommerceItem',
"SKU", // (required) SKU: Product unique identifier
"NAME", // (optional) Product name
"CATEGORYNAME", // (optional) Product category. You can also specify an array of up to 5 categories eg. ["CATEGORYNAME", "CATEGORYNAME2", "CATEGORYNAME3"]
20, // (recommended) Product price
1 // (optional, default to 1) Product quantity
]);
// Here it is important to add all other products found in the order
// Specifiy the order details
_paq.push(['trackEcommerceOrder',
"ORDERID", // (required) Unique Order ID
10.70, // (required) Order Revenue grand total (includes tax, shipping, and subtracted discount)
5.5, // (optional) Order sub total (excludes shipping)
5.5, // (optional) Tax amount
5.5, // (optional) Shipping amount
false // (optional) Discount offered (set to false for unspecified parameter)
]);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

-

```
// Set the view of a product
_paq.push(['setEcommerceView',
"SKU", // (required) SKU: Product unique identifier
"NAME", // (optional) Product name
"CATEGORYNAME", // (optional) Product category. You can also specify an array of up to 5 categories eg. ["CATEGORYNAME", "CATEGORYNAME2", "CATEGORYNAME3"]
20, // (recommended) Product price
]);
// Set the view of a category
_paq.push(['setEcommerceView',
false,
false,
"CATEGORYNAME", // You can also specify an array of up to 5 categories eg. ["CATEGORYNAME", "CATEGORYNAME2", "CATEGORYNAME3"]
]);
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

-

```
// Add all products found in the cart
_paq.push(['addEcommerceItem',
"SKU", // (required) SKU: Product unique identifier
"NAME", // (optional) Product name
"CATEGORYNAME", // (optional) Product category. You can also specify an array of up to 5 categories eg. ["CATEGORYNAME", "CATEGORYNAME2", "CATEGORYNAME3"]
20, // (recommended) Product price
1 // (optional, default to 1) Product quantity
]);
// Specifiy the order details
_paq.push(['trackEcommerceCartUpdate', 15.5]); // (required) Cart amount
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following documentation:

https://help.datatrics.com/en/collections/1864777-tracking-scripts#ecommerce-scripts

The scripts above are better documented and it's much clearer what you need to make "dynamic".

I hope this helps! You can also chat with Datatrics by clicking on the bottom right chat bubble in this documentation.

[Edit] If you are using Google Tag Manager with Enhanced Ecommerce, it's maybe easier to implement those scripts there. There is a copy/paste script which captures all GTM Enhanced Ecommerce data and sends it over to the Datatrics tracking script.